# Corners heuristic pacman (Berkley's AI project)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics, pacman

Can someone please suggest which of the following distance formula to be used for corners heuristic problem?

1. When I use **manhattan distance**, the results are incorrect.
2. When I use **euclidean distance**, the pacman starts moving after 23.5 seconds
   which is the time of finding solution.
3. I was unable to figure out which game state to use for **mazeDistance(pos1,
   pos2, gameState)**?

> ```
> heuristic = 0 currentState, visitedCorners = state copyOfVisitedCorners = list(visitedCorners)
>     for i in range(4):
>             cornerDistance = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>             cornerCounter = 0
>             for corner in copyOfVisitedCorners:
>                 cornerDistance[cornerCounter] = euclidean(currentState,corners[cornerCounter])
>                 cornerCounter += 1
>             cornerCounter1 = 0
>             closestCorner = 0
>             for currentValue in cornerDistance:
>                 if (copyOfVisitedCorners[closestCorner]):
>                     closestCorner = cornerCounter1
>                 if (not copyOfVisitedCorners[cornerCounter1]) and (currentValue < cornerDistance[closestCorner]):
>                     closestCorner = cornerCounter1
>                 cornerCounter1 += 1
>             if (not copyOfVisitedCorners[closestCorner]):
>                 heuristic += cornerDistance[closestCorner]
>                 currentState = corners[closestCorner]
>                 copyOfVisitedCorners[closestCorner] = True
>         return heuristic
> ```

Comment: Share your code, this description is definitely not enough to understand where do your problems come from. Show us some context, show us what you've tried.

Comment: could you edit the OP with that code, with proper formatting (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks )? It's a bit hard to read spread out over comments like that